# How did Ising pronounce his name?

Tags: physics, biographical-details

The surname of [Ernst Ising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Ising), of Ising model fame, is often pronounced as EYE-zing by non-German speakers, but as EE-zing by German speakers. It is frequently [claimed](http://backreaction.blogspot.kr/2008/01/germenglish.html) that EE-zing is the correct pronunciation, as Ising was German. However, he emigrated to the US and lived there for over half his (long) life. It therefore seems possible that in later life he pronounced his name in an Anglicised style as EYE-zing.

One reasonable point of view is that the word "Ising" in "Ising model" should be pronounced in the same way as Ising himself would have done. So my question is: **how did Ising pronounce his own name?**

Although this is a trivial point, given the number of people working on the Ising model worldwide, it would be nice to have some evidence for standardising the pronunciation of this.

(Originally posted on [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202435/how-did-ising-pronounce-his-name), where it was suggested the question should be moved here.)

Comment: I'm closing this question because it is about the biographical details of a scientist that are not relevant to his scientific work, cf. [this meta post](http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/q/1/26).

Comment: If this question is off-topic for this site, please could you let me know a StackExchange site where it would be suitable to ask this question? I do think it's a question where people would be genuinely interested in the answer.

Comment: I don't think there is one, or at least not that I'm aware of. Sorry!

Comment: "Where should I ask X?" questions are best suited for Meta SE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101576/what-is-stackexchanges-policy-regarding-where-should-i-ask-this-question-typ You may also look through the full list of SE sites to see if it fits somewhere http://stackexchange.com/sites# But like Danu I am having hard time thinking of one. History or Linguistics may not like it either. Skeptics maybe, if you rephrase it as skepsis of the accepted pronunciation http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I'm interest in the question. If you find the answer else where, it will be great if you link it here. Thanks

Comment: @Ashley Montanaro: For pronounciation of German names see German Wikipedia: Ernst Ising. Of course the first letter is "ee" like in "see".